# Floating battery negative terminal

Tags: transistors, batteries, grounding, floating

[image: Circuit]

I am building a circuit that uses an op amp comparator stage to control the circuit shown.

The op amp circuit will switch on or off the transistor to drive the motor supplied with a set of AAA batteries in series. The motor ground is connected to the op amp ground and the circuit works fine - the motor turns on when the op amp drives high. However I cannot figure out why this is working as the battery ground is left floating.

How is it possible that the battery ground is floating yet it is still driving the motor? Where the motor is powered from?

Comment: How big is your motor? The op amp output could be driving the motor.

Comment: disconnect the battery positive terminal also

Comment: Are you certain you want to use an emitter-follower here anyway?

Comment: "... to control the circuit shown": Control: how? Draw the **full** schematic.

Comment: Replace BJT with NMOS FET. Does the motor still turn on?

Comment: Yes thank you for the help it turns out the op amp was driving the motor on its own

Comment: @Voltage Spike, Please reopen the OP's question because it is based on right observations and it makes sense. The direct load control through the base-emitter junction is an interesting phenomenon in the transistor implementation of the voltage follower. I have explained it in detail in my answer below. Please, read carefully my explanations. BTW I used it as a useful trick in the 90's to build a stand-by battery supply (UPS) for a home alarm system. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Voltage Spike, Is it a common practice in SE EE not to respond to comments... even for moderators?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist firstly, I have had 200 moderator actions to review because there is a two month backlog, secondly the diagram needs to be edited to show the complete circuit with vcc's so we can determine what the output is and I will be more than happy to open the question, it already has answers, do we need more answers?

Comment: @Voltage Spike♦, Thanks for the responce. I apologize for my insistence but I had no idea of ​​your overwork. Regarding OPs diagram, I think it is fine from the side of the power supply. Its input part can be edited to show where the input current flows to drive the motor. I could draw two pictures (without and with battery connected) if only OP would like it.

Answer (score 2):

The base-emitter junction of the NPN transistor will act as a diode, passing current from the source driving the base to the motor.  The battery will have no effect.

Comment: Agreed. To put it another way, the motor is powered by current flowing through the base of the transistor to the emitter.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the input (base-emitter junction) of bipolar transistors is pretty weird with its "diode behavior". Except for a few cases where we control it by current we do not want that. We would like to control it by voltage... and with sufficiently high voltage. But it can withstand very low voltage (look at its input characteristic to see why).  As the saying goes, its input operating range is small ... and we need to expand it somehow. But how?

Obviously, *we need to remove the excess voltage so that only a few hundred millivolts remain on the base-emitter junction*. We can do it in two ways:

**1. From the side of the base.** First, we can insert a (base) resistor between the input voltage source and the base. In this configuration aka "common-emitter stage" or "transistor switch", we should connect the emitter to ground and insert the motor between the collector and positive terminal of the battery (of course, the negative terminal should be connected to ground to have a circuit). Thus, the input source, base resistor and base-emitter junction are connected in a loop. As a result, a big part of the input voltage is lost across the resistor as a voltage drop… and only a small part is applied across the base-emitter junction.

**2. From the side of the emitter.** But there is a more clever way to solve the problem… and this is your circuit solution. Here, the motor is connected between the emitter and ground so now the input source, base-emitter junction and motor are connected in a loop. At first glance, a slight difference... but in fact, it is crucial. Let's see why…

When the input voltage is applied through the motor to the base-emitter junction, significant base current should flow since the motor has low resistance... and this is your case. But the transistor begins turning on... its beta times bigger collector current adds to the base current and creates significant voltage drop across the motor. Figuratively speaking, the transistor "lifts" its emitter voltage until it approaches the input voltage. As above, a big part of the input voltage is lost, now across the motor, as a voltage drop… and only a small part is applied across the base-emitter junction.

The name of this trick is "emitter degeneration", "bootstrapping" or "series negative feedback". This circuit configuration is called "emitter follower", "voltage buffer" or most unsuccessfully, "common-collector stage"...

---

This was my "fairy tale" about these two basic transistor stages. Remember it well and if someone ever tries to "explain" them to you through definitions and well-memorized phrases, tell it to him/her...